# Make script run once per pageload

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup, window

How do I make the following, run only once per pageload...

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)
        $("#spopup").show("slow");else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
});
```

Here is what I use to close the pop up in case that makes a difference...

```
function closeSPopup(){
    $('#spopup').hide('slow');
}
```

http://codepen.io/john84/pen/vgWVRp

I was reading up on the .one() function but am unsure as where to put it

http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Maybe somrthing like this will help? http://pastebin.com/BsL402Gr

Comment: Thanks but that example didn't fire the script at all.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the function call, redefine the function.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if($(document).scrollTop()>=$(document).height()/5)
    $("#spopup").show("slow");else $("#spopup").hide("slow");
  $(window).scroll(function(){});
});
```

The first time they scroll, it will execute the function (based on your if/else) and after completing that action, it clears the javascript linked to on scroll

Comment: Thanks Peter but unfortunately the popup still persists

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to do this. i think setting a flag is going to work :

```
var isopen = false;
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
    if($(document).scrollTop() >= $(document).height()/5 && isopen == false) {
        $("#spopup").show("slow");
        isopen = true;
        $(window).off('scroll');
    }
});
```